# How to modify rows of numpy arrays stored as a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to modify rows of numpy arrays stored in a list. length of my numpy arrays are not the same. I have several huge numpy arrays stored as list. This is my data (for simplicity I copied only a small list of array):

```
elements= [array([[971, 466, 697, 1, 15, 18, 28],
                 [5445, 4, 301, 2, 12, 47, 5]]),
           array([[5883, 316, 377, 2, 9, 87, 1]])]
```

Then, I want to replace the fourth column of each row with the last one and then delete the last column. I want to have the following result:

```
[array([[971, 466, 697, 1, 28, 18],
        [5445, 4, 301, 2, 5, 47]]),
 array([[5883, 316, 377, 2, 1, 87]])]
```

I tried the following code but it was not successful:

```
length=[len(i) for i in elements] # To find the length of each array
h=sum(length) # to find the total number of rows
for i in range (h):
    elements[:,[4,-1]] = elements[:,[-1,4]]
    elements=np.delete(elements,[-1],1)
```

I am facing the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I appreciate ay help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple inefficient solution:

```
import numpy as np

elements= [np.array([[971, 466, 697, 1, 15, 18, 28],
                     [5445, 4, 301, 2, 12, 47, 5]]),
           np.array([[5883, 316, 377, 2, 9, 87, 1]])]

new_elements = list()
for arr in elements:
    arr[:, 4] = arr[:, -1]
    new_elements.append(arr[:, :-1])
```

The new list output is:

```
new_elements
Out[11]: 
[array([[ 971,  466,  697,    1,   28,   18],
        [5445,    4,  301,    2,    5,   47]]),
 array([[5883,  316,  377,    2,    1,   87]])]
```

Comment: Dear @Mathieu, Thanks for your solution. It is exactly what I wanted.  I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without loops but it's still slower (1.75 times on large data) than accepted solution:

```
counts = list(map(len, elements))
arr = np.concatenate(elements)
arr[:, 4] = arr[:, -1]
new_elements = np.split(arr[:,:-1], np.cumsum(counts)[:-1])
```

Concatenation is quite slow in `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
p=[]
for x in range(len(elements)):
    for y in range(len(elements[x])):
         p.append(list(elements[x][y][:4])+[elements[x][y][-1]]+[elements[x][y][-2]])
print(p)

[[971, 466, 697, 1, 28, 18],
[5445, 4, 301, 2, 5, 47],
[5883, 316, 377, 2, 1, 87]]
```